# Represent all palindromic numbers across number bases based on digit count

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recreational-mathematics, number-systems, palindrome

I've been looking at plots/graphs of [palindromic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindromic_number) across number bases, and noticed that we should be able to represent all $d$ digit palindromes across number bases $y$, with some expression $x_y$ where $x,y\in\mathbb N, y\gt1$.

---

> - Let $P_d\in\mathbb N$ denote an expression $P_d=x_y$ which is always a $d$ digit palindrome and stands for all $d$ digit palindromes ( Represent $x,y$ with $m,n\in\mathbb N$ )

Taking this, I found so far by observing my graphs/plots:

$(1)$ All one digit palindromes are given by following:

$$P_1= (m)_{(m+n)}$$

*( Read: $P_1$ stands for all $1$-digit palindromes, where $x=m$ is always $1$-digit palindrome in number base $y=m+n$, where this holds $\forall m,n\in\mathbb N$)*

$(2)$ Similarly, all two digit palindromes are given by:

$$P_2=\left(m^2+(n+1)m \right)_{(m+n)}$$

*( Read: $P_2$ stands for all $2$-digit palindromes, where $x=m^2+(n+1)m$ is always $2$-digit palindrome in number base $y=m+n$, where this holds $\forall m,n\in\mathbb N$)*

> How can one find $P_d$ for $d=3,4,5,\dots$ ?

**Update:** This can be neatly extended to any $P_d$ but with proper introduction of new variables for each new digit needed, as [String showed in his answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2493013).

If we always have $y=m+n$ then: 
*(I've decremented $k$ by $1$ if you compare this to Strings answer)*

$$ P_d = \left(my^{d-1}+(k_1-1)y^{d-2}+(k_2-1)y^{d-3}\dots +(k_2-1)y^{2}+(k_1-1)y^{1}+m \right)_{(y)}$$

Where all $k_r\in\mathbb N\le y$. For example, take $d=3$:

$$P_3 = (my^2+(k_1-1)y+m)_y $$
$$(*) \space\space\space\space P_3 = \left(m^3+(2n)m^2+(n^2+k_1)m+n(k_1-1)\right)_{(m+n)} $$

---

*P.S. I've decided to accept the answer as It turns out I can work with that. 
I'll still leave my initial thought below.*

> My initial approach was trying to not introduce a new variable. But the failed attempt below shows what happens when you limit $k_1$ to only $3$ values:

$(3?)$ Looking at $d=3$ and using $k\in \{ 0,1,2 \} $, the following is *almost correct*:

$$P_3 = \left(4m^2+(5n-3)m+n^2-3n+1+(n+m)k\right)_{(m+n)}$$

*Almost correct*, since each $m$ has exceptions, which are more numerous the bigger $m$ is. 
For example, all exceptions for $m=1,2,3,4,5,6,7$ below:

If $m=1, n=1, k=2$, then $P_3$ is not a $3$-digit palindrome.

If $m=2$, then increment on $P_3$ for $k=0,1,2$ should be:

 For $n=1$: $+1,+1,+1$

 For $n=2$: $+0,+1,+1$

 For $n=3$: $+0,+0,+1$

If $m=3$, then increment on $P_3$ for $k=0,1,2$ should be:

 For $n=1$: $+1,+1,+2$

 For $n=2$: $+1,+1,+1$

 For $n=3$: $+1,+1,+1$

 For $n=4$: $+0,+1,+1$

 For $n=5$: $+0,+0,+1$

If $m=4$, then increment on $P_3$ for $k=0,1,2$ should be: (Notice we need to include $n=0$)

 (For $n=0$: $+2,+2,+2$)

 For $n=1$: $+1,+2,+2$

 For $n=2$: $+1,+1,+1$

 For $n=3$: $+1,+1,+1$

 For $n=4$: $+1,+1,+1$

 For $n=5$: $+1,+1,+1$

 For $n=6$: $+0,+1,+1$

 For $n=7$: $+0,+0,+1$

If $m=5$, then increment on $P_3$ for $k=0,1,2$ should be: (Include $n=0$)

 (For $n=0$: $+2,+2,+2$)

 For $n=1$: $+2,+2,+2$

 For $n=2$: $+1,+1,+2$

 For $n=3$: $+1,+1,+1$

 For $n=4$: $+1,+1,+1$

 For $n=5$: $+1,+1,+1$

 For $n=6$: $+1,+1,+1$

 For $n=7$: $+1,+1,+1$

 For $n=8$: $+0,+1,+1$

 For $n=9$: $+0,+0,+1$

If $m=6$, then increment on $P_3$ for $k=0,1,2$ should be: (Include $n=0,-1$)

 (For $n=-1$: $+3,+3,+3$)

 (For $n=0$: $+2,+2,+2$)

 For $n=1$: $+2,+2,+2$

 For $n=2$: $+1,+2,+2$

 For $n=3$: $+1,+1,+1$

 For $n=4$: $+1,+1,+1$

 For $n=5$: $+1,+1,+1$

 For $n=6$: $+1,+1,+1$

 For $n=7$: $+1,+1,+1$

 For $n=8$: $+1,+1,+1$

 For $n=9$: $+1,+1,+1$

 For $n=10$: $+0,+1,+1$

 For $n=11$: $+0,+0,+1$

If $m=7$, then increment on $P_3$ for $k=0,1,2$ should be: (Include $n=0,-1,-2$)

 (For $n=-2$: $+3,+3,\emptyset$)

 (For $n=-1$: $+3,+3,+3$)

 (For $n=0$: $+2,+2,+2$)

 For $n=1$: $+2,+2,+2$

 For $n=2$: $+2,+2,+2$

 For $n=3$: $+1,+1,+2$

 For $n=4$: $+1,+1,+1$

 For $n=5$: $+1,+1,+1$

 For $n=6$: $+1,+1,+1$

 For $n=7$: $+1,+1,+1$

 For $n=8$: $+1,+1,+1$

 For $n=9$: $+1,+1,+1$

 For $n=10$: $+1,+1,+1$

 For $n=11$: $+1,+1,+1$

 For $n=12$: $+0,+1,+1$

 For $n=13$: $+0,+0,+1$

And so on for all $m\dots$

In $m=7,n=-2,k=2$ you can see I put "$\emptyset$" symbol. That's because that number is not a $3$ digit palindrome for any increment.

As seen here, for the current $P_3$ as seen above; Bigger $m$ tend to need more increments/offsets for more values of $n$ and start missing more palindromes needing values using $n\lt1$, and also we have these irregularities - numbers not being $3$ digit palindrome for $k=2$ sometimes as seen in $m=1$ and $m=7$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure, what you are after. But the number of $d$-digit palindromes in base $y$ must equal $y^{\lceil d/2\rceil}$ if we include those starting with a zero. If we do not include those, the figure becomes $y^{\lceil d/2\rceil}-y^{\lceil d/2\rceil-1}$. So if your formulas must cover all palindromes of a given length, the number of parameter settings $n,m,k,...$ should reflect the number of palindromes.

---

This works well for $d=2$ using $y=m+n$ since all we need is a choice of base $y$, and a choice of a non-zero digit $m$ in that base, from which we can form:
$$
\begin{align}
P_2&=my+m\\
&=m^2+(n+1)m
\end{align}
$$
which becomes the palindrome $mm$ in base $y$.

---

The formula for $P_3$ could similarly read
$$
\begin{align}
P_3&=my^2+ky+m\\
&=m^3+m(2mn+n^2+1)+k(m+n)
\end{align}
$$
which becomes the palindrome $mkm$ in base $y=m+n$. So were we must choose $k$ in the digit range $0,1,...,y-1$.

---

Regarding $P_4$ we could similarly form
$$
P_4=my^3+ky^2+ky+m
$$
which gives us the palindrome $mkkm$ in base $y=m+n$. For $P_5$ we would need to introduce an extra variable in order continue this approach. Again, I am not sure whether this is anything like what you had in mind.

---

**UPDATE:** From your comment, I see that you rather wanted to express parametrisations in terms of as few variables as possible. This approach in no way achieves this, as it introduces a new variable for every second value of $d$ (i.e. for every new digit introduced).

One major consideration then becomes that the ranges for the "fewer than $\lceil d/\rceil$" variables have to be greater than just $[0,y)$ and $[1,y)$ in order to be able to cover all the cases just by a simple counting argument.

For instance there must be $y^2-y^1=y(y-1)$ $3$-digit palindromes in base $y$, so any choice of variables should be able to range over that many combinations.

Comment: I think you got a typo - shouldn't your $P_3$ equal $m^3+2nm^2+(n^2+1)m+(m+n)k$ after squaring the $y$? Also I think you should write $k\in [0,y)$, as $0,1,\dots,y$ makes it look like $y$ is included in digit choice. Looking at $(3?)$ I was trying to sort the palindromes in a different way (and also was kinda trying to not introduce $k$ which forced itself in for values $k\in\{0,1,2\}$). But letting it be a new variable $\in[0,y)$ sorta collapses to looking at palindromes in rather straightforward way; $mk_1k_2\dots k_{\lceil d/2\rceil-1}\dots k_2k_1m$ which is what you wrote.I'll accept this.

Comment: @Vepir: You are absolutely correct! I got the feeling from you writing $k\in\{0,1,2\}$ that you wanted as limited a range for the new variable as possible. Still, not having to introduce $k$ at all would have been brilliant. I do not actually know whether that is possible, but as per my last comment in the update, not introducing $k$ forces $m,n$ to ranges over more values in order to cover all cases just by the sheer number of palindromes that there are. Perhaps someone will come along and show us how that could be done.

Comment: I've just realized this approach will be sufficient for my intentions, and that my initial thought was overthinking/overcomplicating things; Thus I accepted your answer & updated my post. I'm still interested in seeing if this is possible to do without $k$, but I won't be posting that question unless I have time to play with it more.

Comment: If you're interested; I've managed to write $P_3$ using only two variables $m,n\in\mathbb N$. I've taken $P(3)$ and replaced all $n$'s with some $N(n)$ function which consists of only $n$'s and $m$'s, and replaced all $k$'s with some function $K(n)$ which also only uses $n,m$'s. I believe a similar thing should be possible with all other $P_d$'s; but I'm not sure what's the point since it is much easier to just accept multiple variables and iterate over them ( unless my functions can be simplified ). - I might post this in a new question later.

Comment: @Vepir: That sounds really fascinating, indeed!

Comment: Was simpler than it seems. My idea was (Notice that my $k\in\mathbb N$ and $k\le y$ since I've written $P_3$ with $(k-1)$ where you used $k$) to iterate over $k$ using $n$. I used floor functions and square roots to turn $n=1,2,3,\dots$ into $1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3\dots$ for $m=1$, into $1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3\dots$ for $m=2$, and etc. So, I can instead of $k$ use a function which outputs $1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4$ for $m=1$, etc.; thus I basically iterate over $k$ using $n$, differently for each $m$, in a way to go over all $3$ digit palindromes. This should iterate over all, if I didn't miss anything.

Comment: If you're still interested; I've now posted those functions in my newest question. Let me know what you think. I hope I didn't miss anything.